# Why is my loop in my recursive function infinite?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, recursion, segmentation-fault

I have the following function that recursively checks each square in a sudoku puzzle to make it legal, and I kept getting a segmentation fault when it ran, so I put cout checks everywhere to see where it broke.  Somehow, it stays in the loop and continues to call the addSquare function over and over, without ever ending.  How do I get it to stop?

```
bool DoTheWork::addSquare(int& depth)
{
  depth++;
  cout << depth << endl;
  if(board.checkZeroes()==false){ //if the game is won, return true
    cout << "ifstatement1" << endl;
    return true;
  }
  else {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      cout << "loop1" << endl;
      for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        cout << "loop2" << endl;
        if(this->board.getSquare(i,j)==0) { //go through each
          cout << "ifstatement2" << endl;
          for(int k = 1; k < 10; k++) {
            cout << "loop3" << endl;
            //try each number in that square for legality
            board.setSquare(i,j,k);
            //set that square to the number you are currently on
            if(board.isLegal()==false) {
              cout << "ifstatement3" << endl;
              board.unsetSquare(i,j);
            }
            //if the board is not legal for that number, unset that square
            if(addSquare(depth)==true) {
              cout << "ifstatement4" << endl;
              return true;
            }
            //recursive function, if method is true then it will return true
            board.unsetSquare(i,j);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
  } // bool DoTheWork::addSquare(int& depth)
```

When run in the terminal, it prints the following:
loop 1
loop 2
ifstatement2
loop3
ifstatement3
130964
loop1
...
and onwards until it says "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

The number after "ifstatement3" increases by 1 each time the depth increases.

Including the checkZeroes function below:

```
bool Board::checkZeroes()
{
  bool zeroPresent = false;
//assume there are no zeroes, easier for coding
  for(int i=0; i<9; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<9; j++) {
      if(theBoard[i][j] == 0){
//go through each value of theBoard, if any are 0 return true
        zeroPresent = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return zeroPresent;
} // int Board::checkZeroes()
```

Comment: We need enough code to replicate the problem. Seeing the actual output would help too.

Comment: If you get a segmentation fault, `cout` might not get flushed. You might not see the *entire* output.

Comment: @zmbq He has an `endl` in every `cout` statement, and `endl` flushes.

Comment: Changed it to match current version, added comments, added output from terminal. Possible to help now, or do I need to add more?

Comment: Have you tried a debugger also? like GDB?

Comment: @AxelOmega I tried debugging the program file, "Aprog" with gdb by saying
gdb Aprog
(gdb) run
and then it ran the program, ended in a Segmentation fault, and said malloc.c:3447 and said malloc.c: No such file or directory.

There isn't even a malloc.c in this file and I've never heard of that.

Comment: @JoshBreece What I meant was run it so that you can step through the program one statement at a time, just running it like that in GDB wont tell you much more. OK you can always jump backward in the stack trace after a seg fault. But I would advise you to look at a tutorial how to use GDB (DDD is a graphical front end) personally I use emacs to run GDB.

Comment: @AxelOmega Thanks, I'll look into learning how to use GDB.  Also I added the function it calls every time at the beginning to see if that was the problem with the recursion.  I doubt that it is, but I figured it might help.

Answer (score 1):

You never change the value of `depth` that will cause infinite recursion and a segmentation fault will happen when the stack access memory that should not be accessed.

I would run it in a debugger like GDB or DDD in linux.